# Test class coverage help when using if statement

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am having trouble testing each condition of the do_init method in the test class and I am thinking I have some sort of scoping mind block.

How can I write the test class to test each condition?  I think I am on the wrong track somehow.

MAIN CLASS:

```
public static void do_init()
{
    if (Environment == null)
    {
        Environment = GLOBALCLASS.getEnvironment();

        if (Environment == GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION) 
        {
            Named_Credential = GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Prd;
        }
        else if (Environment == GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_TRAIN)
        {
            Named_Credential = GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Train;
        }
        else if (Environment == GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_STAGE)
        {
            Named_Credential = GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Stage;
        }
        else if (Environment == GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_DEV)
        {
            Named_Credential = GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Dev;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }        
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
static testMethod void do_init_condition1()
{
    main_class.do_init();
}

static testMethod void do_init_condition2()
{
    main_class.do_init();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of modifying GLOBALCLASS.getEnvironment() to be hackable/injectable (e.g. using a [Mocking Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm)), the simple answer would be to restructure your code (not the test):

```
static map<string, string> mapping = new Map<String, String> {
  GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION => GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Prd,
  GLOBALCLASS.ENVIRONMENT_TRAIN => GLOBALCLASS.namedCred_Train,
  ...
};
public static void do_init() {
  Environment = mapping.get(GLOBALCLASS.getEnvironment());
}
```

Note that there's some minor performance implications, because maps take time to instantiate, but 100% coverage can be achieved in any environment with no extra effort.

Note that this is typically considered a rather fragile design. A more robust solution that would easily get 100% coverage would be to use Custom Settings or Custom Metadata to configure each environment. I strongly advise that you reconsider your current design.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox.  I am not familiar with custom settings or custom metadata so will need to investigate.

Comment: could you help me understand why this is a fragile design?  Do you mean the one you just posted or my original?

Comment: @Daryn Every time you add or change a sandbox, you'll have to change your code, too, requiring an entire deployment. It can get messy really quickly. With Custom Metadata, it's just a configuration change, takes a lot less effort to maintain.